# A few ways to transposition or cycle decomposition of permutation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, permutations

I've found exercise with permutation and resolve that but I'm not sure that my resolve is proper.

> Proof that every permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ can be decompose to
>   product of transposition
>
> 1. $(1\ 2),(1\ 3),(1\ 4),\dots,(1\ n)$
> 2. $(1\ 2),(2\ 3),(3\ 4),\dots,(n-1\ n)$
>
> or can be decompose on some number of transpositions $(1\ 2)$ or
>   cycles $(1\ 2\ 3\ \dots\ n)$.

My solution:

**(1)** By induction. For $n=2$ We have $(1\ 2)$, so this is true. Suppose that for $n$ decomposition is possible. For $n+1$ We have

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n+1\\
i_1 & i_2 & i_3 & \cdots & k
\end{array}\right)
$$

where $k\le n$. If $k=n+1$ then rank of permutation can be decrease to $n$. If $k\le n$ then We need to multiple permutation by $(k\ n+1)=(1\ k)(1\ n+1)(1\ k)$ what is expected product. Then last column of permutation has values $\begin{array}{c}n+1\\n+1\end{array}$ and We can leave it.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n+1\\
i_1 & i_2 & i_3 & \cdots & k
\end{array}\right)(1\ k)(1\ n+1)(1\ k)=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n+1\\
i_1 & i_2 & i_3 & \cdots & n+1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Last permutation can be write as

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n\\
i_1 & i_2 & i_3 & \cdots & i_n
\end{array}\right)
$$

and can be decompose to product of transpositions $(1\ 2),(1\ 3),(1\ 4),\dots,(1\ n)$ like in assumption.

**(2)** Proof is analogous. Different is only decomposition of $(k\ n+1)$. We have

$$
(1\ 2)(2\ 3)\cdots(k-2\ k-1)(k-1\ k)(k-2\ k-1)\cdots(2\ 3)(1\ 2)=(1\ k)
$$

So We can write $(k\ n+1)=(1\ k)(1\ n+1)(1\ k)=\cdots$

I don't know how to proof last point :(